# Mobile Responsive for fancybox in Wordpress haven't fit the mobile screen

Tags: mobile, fancybox, fancybox-2, fancybox-3

I’m using fancy box this plug in inside my website. For the PC responsive is very good. But for the mobile responsive, the box is over the mobile screen size. I have adjust my content width but seem not this problem. Anyone know am I need to adjust the fancy box setting or what action I need do to.

The image is the mobile responsive and the fancy box pop out is over the mobile screen size
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV86K.png)

If I setting on media to **Fit the content** it will over the mobile screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmXnV.png)

will become over the screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kyc3.jpg)

I expect the Lightbox is fit the mobile screen

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using an outdated version of Fancybox, probably more than 10 years old.
2. You are using some kind of WP plugin, but there are no official WP plugin, therefore you have to ask this question to the author of that plugin.